# Django does not display block content

Tags: python, html, django

Hello my block content does not work.
My directory looks like this:

```
/first_page
    /templates
        /first_page
            /landingPage.html
        /base.html
```

This is my base.html file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
Text
{% block content %}

{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

this is my landingPage.html file

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

Hello StackOverflow!

{% endblock %}
```

Did I forget to include something? Do I have to change something in the settings?
I will just "text" but not "Hello StackOverflow!"

Comment: Try putting `{% block content %} default content {% endblock %}` in base.html. If it appears, is there an invisible typo in the  block name `content` in landingPage.html?

Comment: Now the output is just "Text default content". I didn't find any typo in landigpage.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the mistake:

I refered in my view to the "parent" file (base.html) instead of the "child" file (landingPage.html).

Answer (score 0):

try to change base.html location to the same directory as landingPage.html
then change 
 `{%extends 'base.html'%} to {%extends 'first_page/base.html'%}`

Comment: try to clear browser cached @GCMeccariello

Comment: doesn't work. Maybe because I am using the free version of PyCharm